# How to convert a image from PNG to JPEG using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I am trying to get image from canvas. [image]PNG image is coming properly but the JPEG is producing a problem. I attached image here.First image is my canvas.Followed by PNG then JPEG.So i want my JPEG image with white background or i need a solution for PNG to JPEG conversion in JS

```
canvas =  $('.jSignature')[0];

            imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
            imgDatajpeg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");                   

            $(".sigCapHolder").append('<img src='+imgData+' /> ')
            $(".sigCapHolder").append('<img src='+imgDatajpeg+' /> ')
```

Comment: Showing us the code that generated those images sure would help

Comment: Cleary is a transparency problem. Put a white background rectangle to your canvas.

Comment: Data =$('.jSignature')[0].getContext("2d");
Data.fillRect(0,0,10,100);
Data.fillStyle="white";
Data.fill();
I tried this but still am getting same issue only

Comment: It won't be displayed black if used in any GUI or web application

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Cause

The reason for this to happen is due to canvas being transparent. However the transparancy color is black with a transparent alpha-channel so it won't show on screen.

JPEG on the other side doesn't support alpha-channel so that black color which is the default is stripped of its alpha channel leaving a black background.

You PNG supports alpha-channel so it is compatible with the way canvas work.

## Solution

To get around this you will have to manually draw in a white background on the canvas *before* you draw in the image:

```
var canvas =  $('.jSignature')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';  /// set white fill style
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

/// draw image and then use toDataURL() here
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I rectified my issue.I tried after drawn and changed dynamically.I hope this answer will help to many people in future.

Comment: This does not seem to work, even though I draw before the image I get just a white image (as if the white rect is above the image that I draw afterwards). Should I do something additional to work?

Answer (score 0):

this works in firefox, oCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for providing this solution.

Comment: @Mohammad please upvote me ...

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative way, using a package to convert black background of transparent image to white or any other other based on the provided HEX value,
in our

```js
const Jimp = require("jimp");

// Read the PNG file and convert it to editable format
Jimp.read("./images/your-image.png", function (err, image) {
    if (err) {
        // Return if any error
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    image.background(0xFFFFFFFF, (err, val) => {
        // Convert image to JPG and store it to 
        // './output/' folder with 'out.jpg' name
        image.write("./output/out.jpg");
    })

});
```