# SVG images not downloading in as pdf in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, svg, jspdf

I am using following code to download the **SVG** images as **PDF**.

```
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.setFontSize(30);
    doc.setFontSize(12);

    doc.text(20, 58, 'Day Chart');
    doc.addImage(dayImgData, 'JPEG', 35, 60, 120, 50);
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

This is working fine in Google Chrome Browser.

But this is not working in Internet Explorer and in Firefox.

Am I missing anything or do I need to add any  plugin to resolve this issue?

[image: Day Chart Image is blank when viewed in FireFox]

> dayImgData is 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCADIAfQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD9U6KKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiuZ1HXdfs/HujaEsOnjR9Rtbp2c72uTNGEIx0VFAb/aLZ/h2/NzPjr4g+LdD17UP7DTSRpXhuHT7jVIbu2lkuLxbqZk2wSLIqwlFQtlkkDE7cJjdQB6ZRXiA+L/j9TpDPF4fZfGtus2ggWU4Om7ruCAC7Pnf6R8tyr/J5PKFO4cej/D3xBrWvaTex+I/sTanpOpXOmXM1lE8UE7RNxIkbu7IGUqdpdsHI3HrQB1FFZniLxJo3hPTV1fXrtre1e7tLFXWF5S09zcR28CBUUsS0ssa5xgbsnABId/b1j/zw1H/wW3H/AMRQBo0Vnf29Y/8APDUf/Bbcf/EUf29Y/wDPDUf/AAW3H/xFAGjRWd/b1j/zw1H/AMFtx/8AEUf29Y/88NR/8Ftx/wDEUAaNFZ39vWP/ADw1H/wW3H/xFNTxFprs6ol+zRttcDT7glTgHB+Tg4IP0IoA06Kzv7esf+eGo/8AgtuP/iKP7esf+eGo/wDgtuP/AIigDRorO/t6x/54aj/4Lbj/AOIo/t6x/wCeGo/+C24/+IoA0aKzv7esf+eGo/8AgtuP/iKP7esf+eGo/wDgtuP/AIigDRorO/t6x/54aj/4Lbj/AOIpp8RaaJFhKX4kZSyr/Z9xkgYyQNnQZH5igDTorO/t6x/54aj/AOC24/8AiKP7esf+eGo/+C24/wDiKANGis7+3rH/AJ4aj/4Lbj/4ij+3rH/nhqP/AILbj/4igDRorO/t6x/54aj/AOC24/8AiKP7esf+eGo/+C24/wDiKANGis7+3rH/AJ4aj/4Lbj/4imv4i01GRXS/VpG2oDp9wCxwTgfJycAn6A0AadFZ39vWP/PDUf8AwW3H/wARR/b1j/zw1H/wW3H/AMRQBo0Vnf29Y/8APDUf/Bbcf/EUf29Y/wDPDUf/AAW3H/xFAGjRWd/b1j/zw1H/AMFtx/8AEUf29Y/88NR/8Ftx/wDEUAaNFZ39vWP/ADw1H/wW3H/xFNk8RabEoaVL9FLBQW0+4AySAB9zqSQB7mgDTorO/t6x/wCeGo/+C24/+Io/t6x/54aj/wCC24/+IoA0aKzv7esf+eGo/wDgtuP/AIij+3rH/nhqP/gtuP8A4igDRorO/t6x/wCeGo/+C24/+Io/t6x/54aj/wCC24/+IoA0aKzv7esf+eGo/wDgtuP/AIij+3rH/nhqP/gtuP8A4igDRorMj8RabNGk0KX7xuoZWXT7ghgehB2cinf29Y/88NR/8Ftx/wDEUAaNFZ39vWP/ADw1H/wW3H/xFH9vWP8Azw1H/wAFtx/8RQBo0Vnf29Y/88NR/wDBbcf/ABFaNABRXmfxM/aR+C3we16Dwz8RvGf9kalc2i38UH9nXdxugZ3RX3QxOo+aNxgnPHTkVQ8C/tXfAL4leKrHwT4J8e/2jrWo+b9mtv7LvYfM8uNpH+eSFUGERjyR0wOcCuZ4zDKp7J1I821rq9+1jkeYYSNX2Lqx572tzK9+1r3uet0UUV0nWFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQBzWsfD7w9rfiaw8YXcmrrqulrttGh1u+htk7ndbRzLDJnjduQ7gADkAYz4vhL4XuJNJ1HxC1/q2q6ZFEj3kuoXEYvGjcyIZ4lk8uYJIzMiyh9hPy4612tFAHEr8GPhyseoRDRLkpqWN4Op3Z+z4lEoFrmX/RAJAHxB5fzKD1ANdH4d8OaP4U0qLRdDt5IbWJnf97PJPI7uxZ3klkZnkdmJJZmLEnJJrTooA87+PH/ACJGmf8AY5+EP/Uh0+vRK87+PH/IkaZ/2OfhD/1IdPr0SgAooooAKKKKACs7S/8Aj+1j/r9X/wBJ4a0aztL/AOP7WP8Ar9X/ANJ4aAH63q1roOkXesXh/c2kTSsM4LYHCj3JwB7mnaPf/wBqaRY6ntC/a7aKfC9BvUNx+dcV8Qkn8Xava+ArJnEUcLajqLJ2RQRFH9WfBx16Gtn4ZXX2zwFos27O228r/vhin/stfK4XO6uLz+pgIr9zGDs+84uHPbyipxX+LmXQ2lTUaSl1/Q6iiiivqjEKKKKACs6f/kYbL/ryuv8A0OCtGs6f/kYbL/ryuv8A0OCgDRooooAKKKKACiiigArO1T/j+0f/AK/W/wDSeatGs7VP+P7R/wDr9b/0nmoA0aKKKACiiigAooooAKzte/48Yv8Ar9s//SiOtGs7Xv8Ajxi/6/bP/wBKI6ANGiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigDO8Of8AIvaX/wBeUH/oArRrO8Of8i9pf/XlB/6AK0aACiiigAooooA/NH/gpf8A8l20L/sUrX/0svK4P9hf/k6fwT/3Ev8A03XNfqJ4m+GPw18a38eq+Mvh54Z169ihFvHc6npNvdSpEGZggeRCQoLMcZxlie5qvoXwh+E3hfVYNd8M/C/wlpGpW27yLyw0S2t54tylW2yIgZcqzKcHkEjvXy9TIKk8w+uc6tzKVvRo+LrcL1qmaf2gqitzqVrO+jTt+BwfjL4RXvjf43x+LWh0e0t9F0/SpIdQm0EzaiZI7m4kaGzvzKotlbCrKojcsjgfLkE80vjH4vv4f127HiDxvDdJYRyXv2nwZIDpeo+fGDa6asOnyPcxFDMPO8u8VMI5LDKn6Por6g+0PnvXo/iHetoWvw6l458PxJfaDNqk2naNby6hdxNbTpKt0sdm/nBZGiDhYwse4nbGB8u7pmofFPTJtE0DTdKuIbXWWch49Kjhh0s293LJMJNsYVBcQmNELD72WHJzXs9FAHin7O3in4x+I7vxCnxVgmg+zmExQT2l1EYLhi/mxwvJplnFJAAF2lJLsg5zMwKk+10UUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFedfEiDxSfEXh2Dwv8RNd0q61S9igGm21rp8to1vEfMuZpfOtnmH7oFMrIo3PHjBOSAei0V4O/jLx9ol3qnh/wAR6/4p07WdV1OCGylv4NHeytbCXURALizNuhfISWIYu9x3FTsYBgfSPhjqmsajouoWut6u+rTaTq95pqajJFFHJdxxSYV3ESrHvHKtsVRlDwOgAMv48f8AIkaZ/wBjn4Q/9SHT69Erzn4+O0fgTT3WNpGXxj4RIRcZY/8ACQ6fwMkDJ9yBXa/2pff9C5qP/fy3/wDjtAGjRWd/al9/0Lmo/wDfy3/+O0f2pff9C5qP/fy3/wDjtAGjRWd/al9/0Lmo/wDfy3/+O0f2pff9C5qP/fy3/wDjtAGjWMl/baWPEGpXsmyC1uPNkb0VbaEmrH9qX3/Quaj/AN/Lf/47Xn3ii/u/EOtS+BrfTLxTfX0d7qEavFvFokMQK5D7QWZRznHTvkV5ec5hLLcHKtTV6jtGC7zk+WK9LtX7K76F0488rPY6H4b2FzLY3fi7VIit/wCIZvtRDcmODpCn0C8/Qim/CjMPhu50vp/Zup3dpt/u4k3Y/wDHvaugTUbuNFjj8M6gqqAqqHtgAB0H+trkvA9/dWWt+LNPTRb2Q/2p9raNXhzGZkB5zIBk47E14VPL45Pi8upJ3dqsG+spSiqkpPzlKm5PzNXL2kZv0/y/U9AorO/tS+/6FzUf+/lv/wDHaP7Uvv8AoXNR/wC/lv8A/Ha+xOc0aKzv7Uvv+hc1H/v5b/8Ax2j+1L7/AKFzUf8Av5b/APx2gDRrOn/5GGy/68rr/wBDgo/tS+/6FzUf+/lv/wDHaoTaleHXbNzoF+GFpcgJvgyQXh5H7zGBgd88jGecAHQUVnf2pff9C5qP/fy3/wDjtH9qX3/Quaj/AN/Lf/47QBo0Vnf2pff9C5qP/fy3/wDjtH9qX3/Quaj/AN/Lf/47QBo0Vnf2pff9C5qP/fy3/wDjtH9qX3/Quaj/AN/Lf/47QBo1nap/x/aP/wBfrf8ApPNR/al9/wBC5qP/AH8t/wD47VDUtSvGvNKJ0C/UrdsQC8GWPkSjAxJ15zzgYB74BAOgorO/tS+/6FzUf+/lv/8AHaP7Uvv+hc1H/v5b/wDx2gDRorO/tS+/6FzUf+/lv/8AHaP7Uvv+hc1H/v5b/wDx2gDRorO/tS+/6FzUf+/lv/8AHaP7Uvv+hc1H/v5b/wDx2gDRrO17/jxi/wCv2z/9KI6P7Uvv+hc1H/v5b/8Ax2qGtalePZxhtAv0H2u1OWeDGRPGQOJDyeg7ZPOBzQB0FFZ39qX3/Quaj/38t/8A47R/al9/0Lmo/wDfy3/+O0AaNFZ39qX3/Quaj/38t/8A47R/al9/0Lmo/wDfy3/+O0AaNFZ39qX3/Quaj/38t/8A47R/al9/0Lmo/wDfy3/+O0AaNFZ39qX3/Quaj/38t/8A47R/al9/0Lmo/wDfy3/+O0AHhz/kXtL/AOvKD/0AVo1z+galeR6FpqLoF/Iq2kIDq8GGGwcjMgOPqAav/wBqX3/Quaj/AN/Lf/47QBo0Vnf2pff9C5qP/fy3/wDjtH9qX3/Quaj/AN/Lf/47QBo0Vnf2pff9C5qP/fy3/wDjtaNAH5p/8FLf+S7aF/2KVr/6WXlcH+wx/wAnTeCf+4l/6brmvvf44/sh/DX4/eLLTxj4x1vxNZ3tnp0emRx6Zc28cRiSWWQEiSFzuzM3OcYA46k5Pwo/Yd+E/wAHvH2l/Ebwz4h8W3OpaR5/kRX13bPA3mwvC25UgRj8sjEYYcgdelfG1ckxc80+tpLk509+iaP6HwPiTkWH4KeRzlL2/sJ07crtzSjJLXtdrU3vin8R/GHgbxT4gvotVRPDVj4bi3q0EZNhfzfa/Iut5GSheGOJlbKguhwAGzGn7Rt1F4n1fQD4A1m607QrKZrjVksr5Y2uYbXz3VpTaCzSNuEVhdM+9gPKA5r16/0DQtVivYdU0WwvI9Rtxa3iXFski3MA3YjkDA70G9/lOR8zeprn/EHwl+HfiO51DVbrwjpNvreo6dLpT63bWECakls6FCiXBQuF2nG0kr2II4r7I/ng8v1D9pHx1o3gD/hNdb+E1tZztfzRwaZ9q1prq5sYoVeW5jg/sf7SpVm2ESwRxjG4yhSpPQeHfij431zxdeWGr6Jpun6ND4lttL02aw1JpLi4il037URdRS221QNynMUgOTtzhCZb3g39m74U+E/Cx8I33hnS/Elh9uOopHq2iaaIYp9gTfFbW1tDbxHaMbkiVjkliSc13C+C/ByapJrieE9GXUpUijkvBYRCd0iVliUybdxCLI6qM8B2Axk0AbNFZFl4R8J6bLBNp3hjSbWS1KmB4LKJGiKxeSpUhflxF+7GOifL04rXoAKKKKACmu2xGfaTtBOAOT9KdTJTiNzv2YU/N/d96AOH8B/GbwZ8RbuGx8Pve+bPZm7QzQgLlPK86HcpK+bEZ4lkXPysxXJKsB3deA/Ai78ZyeNJtF8S+I9B12LS9Olu7e/TVbe+vbiC8Fq0UqD/AI+IYneK5cq6qmHiVC4jBX36gAqB7Cxe9j1J7OBruGN4Y7gxgyJGxUsgbqFJVSR0JUegqeigDm7T4bfDrT7TVNPsPAPhy2tdbJOpwQ6VAkd8TnPnqFxL1P3s9TWzpOkaToGnW+j6Fpdpp1haII4LW0gWGGJB/CiKAqj2Aq3RQB538eP+RI0z/sc/CH/qQ6fXoled/Hj/AJEjTP8Asc/CH/qQ6fXolABRRRQAUUUUAR3FxDaW8t1cyLHDCjSSO3RVAySfwrh/hkTrdzrfja6hZLjVLsRRKwwUtkRTGPxDAn1wDVj4i3M2p/2f4FsJSlxrsuLhl6xWicyN7ZxgZ68it/QreG0m1O0toxHDDdRxxoOiqLaEAD8BXzf/ACNM5/6d4X8as1/7ZTf31O6Nvgp+b/L/AIf8jK+KPxG0D4TeA9X8feJJMWelQGQRhsPPKeI4V/2ncqo9M5PANcx8KfFEfizWj4qhRETxX4c0rWwinIXdCPl/DcRzzxXnGs6Zb/tWfGG90S7Bn+GXw1lltpscxavr7IVI/wBpLdWP/AiOqvxW/ZC1W5fwt4MsdQb/AE/TNN1Pw1dgchZLS9dlX8IynpXn51i5yxmEqr+HGrGz7t3pN+n7yy72bPscXkOHwOSOrJv60pQc10jCpGUoR/xLk5pdueMd0z6hooor7Q+ICiiigArOn/5GGy/68rr/ANDgrRrOn/5GGy/68rr/ANDgoA0aKKKACiiigAooooAKztU/4/tH/wCv1v8A0nmrRrO1T/j+0f8A6/W/9J5qANGiiigAooooAKKKKACs7Xv+PGL/AK/bP/0ojrRrO17/AI8Yv+v2z/8ASiOgDRooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAzvDn/ACL2l/8AXlB/6AK0azvDn/IvaX/15Qf+gCtGgAooooAKKKKAPIPi/wCPfFnhbxLbafoWq/ZbeSxSZk8iJ8uZJATllJ6KPyrM+G3xJ8a6/wCNdO0jV9a8+0n87zI/s0S7tsTsOVUEcgHrXR/FD4X6/wCNdft9V0q80+KKKzS3ZbiR1bcHdsjahGMMO/rWf4C+EHiXwt4ssdd1C+0yS3tfN3rDLIXO6JlGAUA6sO9fgWNwXGL4xVWk631T20HpOXJyc0eb3ea3La91a1j04yw/sLO3Nb53Nnxb8YI/CPjDUPC974fd4LbQW1W2vvtQVJ7kLcP9kZdp2M0dtIyvlgdrDAIG7T/4W54Hi1CfSbzUbmC6tbRru4Y6fdNbJsi86SJbkR+TJMsYLGJXMgUZ24o8bfCnw149tNdtNauNQj/t6xt7GWS2mWOS38h5XjlhbadsgMzcnIIAGMZzzMf7M3w2i8e6j8QUtgL3VrSa1u4zpmml5DLB5DyC8Nr9uRinG1bgJ1+XBxX76eYdD4s+Mfg3wfe6Zp1/Hrd7Pql9bWCJpmi3V6YnnjeSJ5BFG21Csbc847jAJEd38bvh/aaddauZfENxY2V9Jp9xc2nhfVLmKOWMuJCXit2HloY3DS58tSMFgSKp2vwTtILVRcfEDxXealHe2d9Fqtw1ibmJrZXSNAq2wh2mOR0bMZJDE5DfNVX4g/s7+C/iR4UsvBuu3+oDT7K7u7sKbexuhK1w7u4aO6t5YsgyHY6oJEx8rjLZAO38M+JovEsmriC3VI9M1A2SSLJvE6+TFKJBwMZEuMc9M55wNusbwz4W0/wrDeQadNcSLe3AuZDMykhhDHFgYA42xKfqT9Bs0AFFFFABTZP9W/yhvlPB7+1Opsn+rbL7OD83p70AeE/AKzsW1G0uruz0rSdVt7O9J0lLC/027tRNLB5iGC8d2niXyIkSZSiBVQIiqQq+8V4P8BpryTxM9tZeLLHUbG00lkvXXXrq8l1eUzL5GoC3uEXyAyibc0bMjlwAzhFI94oAKKK8Z+JuuwaN8W/Dkk2tW94ZIrWCHQrfxnd6ff8AmNcsDcJpsP7u+jwy7vNICrE3XkUAezUV8tJ4ynMcNxD4/wBXYXNun/CwP+J1Ow0OU6hbowAL/wDEuIia5X935eEXf1UPXtXwbvjf+E7iS11i51bSU1S8j0e/uLt7t7mxEh8t/Pclpl+8FkZmLKFOW6kArfHj/kSNM/7HPwh/6kOn16JXnPx8Mg8CaeYUVpB4x8I7VZtoJ/4SHT8AnBwPfBrtfP8AEP8A0C9O/wDA9/8A4zQBo0Vnef4h/wCgXp3/AIHv/wDGaPP8Q/8AQL07/wAD3/8AjNAGjTXdY1LuwVVGSScAD1qh5/iH/oF6d/4Hv/8AGa5T4gar4hlsbfwnbWllDe+IZDaRtHdu5SPGZXIMa/KF4Jz36GvPzXHxyvB1MVJX5VouspPSMV5yk1FebKhHnkokvgNG8Q6vqvj+4XKXjmy03I+7axsRuH+8wyfcGuD+PfxG17w7Zy/Db4dvv8eePdT/ALM0cKebOL7ND9ovWwDhYkJOfUg87SK9J1DVz8P/AAlcanqVppVho2g2TTTSvfyYjhiTJJ/c5JwPqT7mvGP2dNI8S+PvFHiH9pfxPoFvFqXibZZaDZ3dyyNpujqitEFxGctKGRy3GRgjAYivNwODqYDCU8DzXqzvKpJd5O85fNu0eyt0R9LktGjS9pnGLjelRsoxe06j+CHmlbnn/dVtHJHs3wt+HGg/CbwHpHgLw4h+y6XAEeZlw9zMeZJn/wBp2JY+mcDgCvn34QA+Ffjn468HZIXS/Hc+oonQJFq9osiKB6fujgdO4619Oef4h/6Benf+B7//ABmvl7xwNU8LftcNf3FrBDH4g0DTdX+W4JjeezuzBs3FF/5ZyAnjgHr2rg4xhHD5ZCtBWVKcJeihJS/OKOjJcTVzKGYQxEuadWm53e7nGcZN/wDgLn959ZUVnef4h/6Benf+B7//ABmjz/EP/QL07/wPf/4zX2J8gaNFZ3n+If8AoF6d/wCB7/8Axmjz/EP/AEC9O/8AA9//AIzQBo1nT/8AIw2X/Xldf+hwUef4h/6Benf+B7//ABmqE02u/wBu2ZOm2HmfZLnav218Eb4cknyuD04xzk9McgHQUVnef4h/6Benf+B7/wDxmjz/ABD/ANAvTv8AwPf/AOM0AaNFZ3n+If8AoF6d/wCB7/8Axmjz/EP/AEC9O/8AA9//AIzQBo0Vnef4h/6Benf+B7//ABmjz/EP/QL07/wPf/4zQBo1nap/x/aP/wBfrf8ApPNR5/iH/oF6d/4Hv/8AGaoalNrpvNKL6bYBhdtsAvXIJ8iXg/uuBjJzzyAO+QAdBRWd5/iH/oF6d/4Hv/8AGaPP8Q/9AvTv/A9//jNAGjRWd5/iH/oF6d/4Hv8A/GaPP8Q/9AvTv/A9/wD4zQBo0Vnef4h/6Benf+B7/wDxmjz/ABD/ANAvTv8AwPf/AOM0AaNZ2vf8eMX/AF+2f/pRHR5/iH/oF6d/4Hv/APGaoa1Nrps4xLptgq/a7XBW9cnPnx4H+qHBOAT2HPPSgDoKKzvP8Q/9AvTv/A9//jNHn+If+gXp3/ge/wD8ZoA0aKzvP8Q/9AvTv/A9/wD4zR5/iH/oF6d/4Hv/APGaANGis7z/ABD/ANAvTv8AwPf/AOM0ef4h/wCgXp3/AIHv/wDGaANGis7z/EP/AEC9O/8AA9//AIzR5/iH/oF6d/4Hv/8AGaADw5/yL2l/9eUH/oArRrn9Am10aFpoh02waMWkO1mvXUkbBgkeUcH2yav+f4h/6Benf+B7/wDxmgDRorO8/wAQ/wDQL07/AMD3/wDjNHn+If8AoF6d/wCB7/8AxmgDRorO8/xD/wBAvTv/AAPf/wCM1o0AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUyXPlPtTcdpwucZ9qfWH418V6d4L8OXOv6nbXtzHG8VvHb2UfmXE800ixRRxgkDczuqjJAGckgc0AeIfCfTdZPjzRZPK8W6DFbaPcw2Gn64kU0NvGk1sb62jVraGdUEjRLFK0rqwiYooQKX+i6+df2bdJj0fxFe6XoPjibUtBtI7sxWEWh3lqsFw7W6SpdyNutxdI8EhdQ295J532qM5+iqACiiigAooooA87+PH/ACJGmf8AY5+EP/Uh0+vRK87+PH/IkaZ/2OfhD/1IdPr0SgAooooAK4fwl/xVPivVPG8g3WltnTNLzyCin95IP95uh9Mir3xF1e6sdDXStKJOp61KLC0AOCC/DP7ALnntkVynxc8fWnwG+FkMeg2X2/XLpotG8O6coy99qU3EY2jqNxLt0zgjIJFfL46rHHZpGlP+Fhl7SfnUaapx/wC3VebXd02ehgMFWx1WGGw6vOo+Vfq32Xd7JXbOK+LEs3x++LNn+z7pUjt4T8NNBrPju4jJ2zEEPa6bkd3YB2wegyCChB920WGG3uNUt7eJIoortEREUKqqLaEAADoAO1cZ8BfhSfhN4Ej0zU7v+0PEmrzvq3iLUmOXvNRmO6Vt3dVJ2r04XOASa7bS/wDj+1j/AK/V/wDSeGvcwlKSTrVfjlv5LpH5fndnfnuNozlDL8E70KN1F/zyfx1P+32tOqgox6GjXzL+1tpb2Xj74V+M4pDAi3epaLcSA/f86282FD/wOAkY719NV4l+15pH234T22uBdzeG/EWkarjGTtF0kL4/4BO5+ma8rizC/XcjxVFdYS/BXHwtV9nmtOH/AD8Uqf8A4MhKH5yPZrK5W8s4LtcYniWQY9GAP9anrB8CXX2zwXok5OT9hhQn1KqFP6it6vVy/EfXMJSxH88Yy+9JngyXLJoKKKK7CQrOn/5GGy/68rr/ANDgrRrOn/5GGy/68rr/ANDgoA0aKKKACiiigAooooAKztU/4/tH/wCv1v8A0nmrRrO1T/j+0f8A6/W/9J5qANGiiigAooooAKKKKACs7Xv+PGL/AK/bP/0ojrRrO17/AI8Yv+v2z/8ASiOgDRooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAzvDn/ACL2l/8AXlB/6AK0azvDn/IvaX/15Qf+gCtGgAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKoa5oOjeJtMl0fX9OgvrKZkZ4Zlyu5GDIw9GVlVgRyCARyKv0UAcp4N+GnhvwDNOfC8+swW1y8sslnc6vdXkHmyPveRVuHfYxYsTtIBLEkZNdXRRQAUUV5F8Uo/DF58RPC1pfeD9Zk1SCe2u4/ENt4dvb5bONJ8i3iuIInWBpWG2QsUXyi28n5RQB67RXzJb+GTYf8JRZ6b4Fi1LRbvVIb3XL228CXmlahe251HzJrSYTZfVF8p5DuiXaUQrtbeBXsHwb00aX4TuIbPR7jSdJl1S8m0iwntHtWtrFpCY08hwGhX7zLGQpUMBtX7oAK3x4/wCRI0z/ALHPwh/6kOn16JXnPx8RpPAmnosjRs3jHwiA64yp/wCEh0/kZBGR7giu1/su+/6GPUf+/dv/APGqANGis7+y77/oY9R/792//wAarnfHV7qfh7QXlsvEGoS6heSLaWUOy3zJM5wOkYPAyevauTH42lluFqYut8ME2++nRd29kur0KjFzkoor6RJF4m8b6j4quZFGmeHVewsncgJ5uMzy5PHA+XPTGPSvMPhTFL+0B8Wrv9oDVYmbwj4YafR/AlvIp2ztnbdalggcsV2J7A5AKAnP+L9trOpXHh79lPwD4ivUv/ElubrxPdRLGV07Rd3+kPnZu3TMSiAt3weGBr3jw74LtfCmhWHhnw/qt7Zabpdulra28cdvtjjQYUf6rJ4HJPJPJ5rwcjwVVU/9p+Ny9pU86kteXzVNWiv8MezPrFJZHlvtlpXxEXGPeFHaUvJ1XeK/uKfSaZ0VZ2l/8f2sf9fq/wDpPDR/Zd9/0Meo/wDfu3/+NVQ03TbxrzVQNfv1K3agkJBlj5ERycx9eccYGAO+SfqT5E6CuM+M/h9/FXwk8Y+H4V3T3uiXiW/y7sTiJjEcd8OFOPaui/su+/6GPUf+/dv/APGqQ6VekEHxHqJB6jy7f/41UVaaqwdOWzVvvN8LiJYSvDEQ3g016p3OV+B+qJq3wy0e6jORtkx9C5YfowrvK8g+AWkz6b4WvvCset3cD6BqEmnskYhbPlARbjuQnlo29q9O/su+/wChj1H/AL92/wD8ar5/hGTeR4WEt4QUH6w9x/8ApJpj4Rp4qpCGybt6XNGis7+y77/oY9R/792//wAao/su+/6GPUf+/dv/APGq+jOQ0azp/wDkYbL/AK8rr/0OCj+y77/oY9R/792//wAaqhNpt4Nds0Ov35Y2lyQ+yDIAeHgfu8YOR2zwMY5yAdBRWd/Zd9/0Meo/9+7f/wCNUf2Xff8AQx6j/wB+7f8A+NUAaNFZ39l33/Qx6j/37t//AI1R/Zd9/wBDHqP/AH7t/wD41QBo0Vnf2Xff9DHqP/fu3/8AjVH9l33/AEMeo/8Afu3/APjVAGjWdqn/AB/aP/1+t/6TzUf2Xff9DHqP/fu3/wDjVUNS028W80oHX79i12wBKQZU+RKcjEfXjHORgnvggA6Cis7+y77/AKGPUf8Av3b/APxqj+y77/oY9R/792//AMaoA0aKzv7Lvv8AoY9R/wC/dv8A/GqP7Lvv+hj1H/v3b/8AxqgDRorO/su+/wChj1H/AL92/wD8ao/su+/6GPUf+/dv/wDGqANGs7Xv+PGL/r9s/wD0ojo/su+/6GPUf+/dv/8AGqoa1pt4lnGW1+/cfa7UYZIMZM8YB4jHI6jtkc5HFAHQUVnf2Xff9DHqP/fu3/8AjVH9l33/AEMeo/8Afu3/APjVAGjRWd/Zd9/0Meo/9+7f/wCNUf2Xff8AQx6j/wB+7f8A+NUAaNFZ39l33/Qx6j/37t//AI1R/Zd9/wBDHqP/AH7t/wD41QBo0Vnf2Xff9DHqP/fu3/8AjVH9l33/AEMeo/8Afu3/APjVAB4c/wCRe0v/AK8oP/QBWjXP6Bpt5JoWmuuv38ataQkIqQYUbBwMxk4+pJq//Zd9/wBDHqP/AH7t/wD41QBo0Vnf2Xff9DHqP/fu3/8AjVH9l33/AEMeo/8Afu3/APjVAGjRWd/Zd9/0Meo/9+7f/wCNVo0AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAed/Hj/kSNM/7HPwh/wCpDp9eiV538eP+RI0z/sc/CH/qQ6fXolABXjvxH+I2g+FbnXPiT4jl3aF4Ct2jghU83mpSfKI09WyVQccE56Zr0bxp4h/4Rjw5dapGA1zgRWseMl5m4QAd+ecegNfOXg3w8fjZ8VbXSpm+1eA/hRema8kPzRa14oPLZP8AGluGxnucdVfj5HO60sdmFHLKWvLapLtdN+zT8uZOo/8Ar2l9pH0OQZfSxM54nF3VCkuabW7X8q/vTbUI9ruW0Wejfs4fDnXtA0fU/iZ8RY93jzx9Oup6vuXmyhxi3slz91Yo8AjruJBJ2g17HRRX1FCjHD01Tj0/Hu35t6s83M8wq5rip4utZOXRbRS0jFLpGKSil0SQVnaX/wAf2sf9fq/+k8NaNZ2l/wDH9rH/AF+r/wCk8NbHAaNFFFAHmvgg2GjfFXxn4fgEge88rUVDHg5w8pH/AAO5H5V6VXh/xU+IXhb4N/FXTPHHi67ew0a901rG+u0tZJxHuLMrFYlZ/vQQrkA/eGeKmsf2zv2ZNR2fZ/ivYpvJA8+zuoOnr5kQx+NfJ8O4vD4WnXwlSai4VqujaWkpua38pn0P9g5pmVKGMwmGqVINayjCUldaNNpNJ6J287ntVFeZWP7TX7Pmobfs/wAY/CibztHn6lHDz7+YRge5resfjD8I9T2/2b8UvCF3vO1fI1y2k3H0G1zk19LHE0J/DNP5o4KuS5lQ/i4ecfWEl+aOvrOn/wCRhsv+vK6/9DgpLHxL4c1Pb/Zuv6bd722L5F1HJlvQYJ59qWf/AJGGy/68rr/0OCtk1LVHBOnOm7TVn5mjRRRTICiiigAooooAKztU/wCP7R/+v1v/AEnmrRrO1T/j+0f/AK/W/wDSeagDRooooAKKKKACiiigArO17/jxi/6/bP8A9KI60azte/48Yv8Ar9s//SiOgDRooooAKKKKACiivJ/ib8dfCXhNzo6+L9G0mRiVn1K/uUSKDH3hGp5mkH91Qcd+hx5maZthsopKpiHq9IxWspPtFdX3eiS1bSTZ0YXC1sbUVHDxcpPok2/uR6ml1bSTy2sdxG00IUyRq4LIG6ZHUZwcVLXzN4N+MXwc8Q6/HB8JfiA+oeKoQ0jLqMU1uuvqW/eJEZlUO4I4C8+mfvD6E8NeI9O8U6VHqmnMQCdksTcPDIPvIw7Ef4GvPyjPZY2q8Li4KnV+KKUuaMo+UkleUb2mujs1eMkzpzHKsXlc1TxdOUJdpRcX9z6f8NuiTw5/yL2l/wDXlB/6AK0azvDn/IvaX/15Qf8AoAqTWNZ0zQNPk1TV7tLe2iHLt3PYAdST6DmvfrVqeHpyq1pKMYq7bdkkurfRHnpNuyLM88NtC9xczJFFGpZ3dgqqB1JJ6CsHwx470DxbdXlppM7l7Q5HmLt82Pp5iA8lc5H5eorCg0zWfiRMmoeIoptO8OKwe200nbLd45DzEdF7hf8A9Z0PGPhi58qz8ReFYI4dX0Rf9HiRdqzwD71uQOxGceh6YzkfJ1c3zTER/tDBUv8AZoa2aftKsesoL7KS96Ka5qlrWimm9lTgvck9fwX9fgdfRWX4a8Q2PijR4NYsCQso2yRt96KQfeRvcH+h6GtSvqsNiaWMoxxFCSlCSTTWzT2Zi04uzCiiithBRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQBna/r+leGNJn1vWrloLS32hikTyuzMwVUSNAXd2YhVVQWYkAAk0zw34l0bxdpMet6DcyTWsjvH+9t5IJY5EYq6SRSqskbqwIKuoII5FZvxB8P6t4h0GKLQWtP7SsL+01K1jvJHjgleCZZPLd0VmQMFI3BWxkHacYpPh/4f1fQdJvJPEH2NdT1bUbjU7qKzlaWCF5W4jSR1RnCqFG4ouTk7V6AAwfj4PM8AWttkqt14q8LWrsPvKkuu2MbFT2YBiQexwe1aA8MeO9C+bw54y/tCFTxa6xH5nH/XVfm/TFbHjfwR4Y+I3hi78HeMtNa/0i+aF54FuJYCzRSpLGQ8TK6kSRo3DDp6ZFeZ/8Mcfs7f8AQkX/AP4Umqf/ACTXh5plMcfUVWMWppWUo1J05Ly91NNeUrryPSwX1Jwf1qpKL7RpxmvvdSFn8vmcT+0L44+Jc994b+Huj6NDY+MPEMz2uixw3IlVJCMS37Y5RII9zA8kNg4IBA90+Fvw40H4TeA9I8BeHEP2XS4AjzMuHuZjzJM/+07EsfTOBwBXAwfsc/s72t4NQtfBWoQ3SoYxPH4k1RZAh6ruFznHtVi6/ZI+A18qpe+F9YuFU5US+KdWcA+2bmuTKcnxOWVKteb9rUqO7lKWtkkkvdppbJbJbd7t7Zxm3+yU8tyqF6SfNJzfJKc9UrxSqJRhHSK5nq5PTmsvYaK8V/4Y2/Z1/wChIv8A/wAKTVP/AJJpk37F/wCzfcxNBceAryWN/vI/iLVGU/UG5r2+fF/yR/8AA3/8gfMe0x3/AD7h/wCBy/8AlZ7bWbphAvdYJOALxcn/ALd4a8Y/4YX/AGWP+iXf+VvUf/kij/hhf9lj/ol3/lb1H/5Ipe0xv/PuP/gb/wDkCfa5h/z6h/4Ml/8AKz2r+39C/wCg1Yf+BKf40f2/oX/QasP/AAJT/GvE/wDhhP8AZW/6Jc3/AIPdS/8Akij/AIYT/ZW/6Jc3/g91L/5Io58b/JH/AMCf/wAgHPmH/PuH/gcv/kDvfFr3E3iLSfEfhfV9BknsoZ4ZUu7wKrK+3H3Tk/xfpWbfaj4gv951bQvAWo+aAGD3atkDpu35z2/KuU/4YT/ZW/6Jc3/g91L/AOSKP+GE/wBlb/olzf8Ag91L/wCSK+frZDip16lejVlT9o+ZqM1a/Ko3tKlLdRVzohi8zp2tThp/fl/8gXb3wzoOpbzqXwh+Fl55gw4mS0cuB2O5Dn8awr74U/C/UN32j9nf4aJvG0+RcWcPHt5ajB9xWh/wwn+yt/0S5v8Awe6l/wDJFH/DCf7K3/RLm/8AB7qX/wAkVhLh3Hy/5iZ/fTf54dnfS4g4gofwpKPpVqL8onI3v7PfwSu94uv2dvDTl12lrXxX9nAHsFkGD7isZ/2cfg/Z38K6Z8LbzRU8mV1j07x7IWDBkHmKWlOCMgY75z/DXo//AAwn+yt/0S5v/B7qX/yRR/wwn+yt/wBEub/we6l/8kVi+F8c9ViX91D/AOZb/iehDjXi2muVV5W7e3rW+61jgP8AhR2iW/8AyB9d+KOkgcoLL4houx/743Bvm6fkKP8AhW3iix+XSvjf8aomX5h9r8VWt6BJ65ZBuXgfL0PPrXf/APDCf7K3/RLm/wDB7qX/AMkUf8MJ/srf9Eub/wAHupf/ACRS/wBWs0Xw4t/+U/0oor/XXid/HyS/xS5v/SqbOA/sL432H/Hh+0R42hX7y/aNJ02+O/1OWHy8D5enX1p6al+1DZD918e5dRx83+l+BrCLn+7+7m6e/Xmu8/4YT/ZW/wCiXN/4PdS/+SKP+GE/2Vv+iXN/4PdS/wDkij/V7O18ONl9/wDlBL8A/wBcM8l8eGw0vWnSf4+wv+JwH/Cyv2t7Pi213wnqP8Wbzw7PCc/3f3cvT3681atPjf8AtbRA/wBpeFfhjIc5CxJqkR2/ju/Ou1/4YT/ZW/6Jc3/g91L/AOSKP+GE/wBlb/olzf8Ag91L/wCSKFknEkdY4771f9BPinHTVqmX4Z/Jx/8ASYI5+P8AaG+P9tGzXvwo8J3RHIFvrN1Fx6fPbnn8al/4aU+Jd3cWct/8B4rf7NcGVRF4nWXfmKRCObZcH5s9+hrb/wCGE/2Vv+iXN/4PdS/+SKP+GE/2Vv8Aolzf+D3Uv/kitFlnFUdsbD5wT/RHPLO5zXvZbQv5VKy/JpfgSQ/tP6mGkS9+DevoVOFMOoWbhv8AvqRSPyrWT9pfQiCZfh54xh9A66f830xdn/JrF/4YT/ZW/wCiXN/4PdS/+SKP+GE/2Vv+iXN/4PdS/wDkitFguLI/8xVF+tKX6TRzTzKpLbA0l6Vav6pnZWvx88F3G7zrPVrXbjHmwRnd9Njt+uOtX0+N3wzkHGvTj2bTLof+068+/wCGE/2Vv+iXN/4PdS/+SKs/8MTfsz/9E+u//Ci1T/5JrVUeLI71sO/+4dRf+5TnWIqTfv0IxXlUf60/1O+/4XH8ONpb/hIjgf8ATlcZ/wDQKp6j8c/h5Yqpi1G4vGcEhIbdlbj/AK6ba5EfsXfs3CMxDwDd7CdxX/hItUxn1x9oqqf2GP2WWJZvhcSTySdc1H/5IolR4skre1w69IVH+dT/ADCpVlCzpUlLunUa/KmzsNO+Pfga9nEF3HqWnZzte5gUhhjOQInc4/DuKv3fxN8CaxaIll4ig3LdWrkTI8PyieMk/vFXoASfpXFQ/sX/ALN1vCLeDwFdxxKMBE8RaoqgfQXFXLf9kb4CWbbrTwrq8B9Y/FGrKf0uacKPFVLerQn6wnF/epNf+SlQrOo71KSh6TcvzhH8zs9Q+Lfw80xttz4kjc/9O9vNOO3eNG9f5+hrnrv9orwFHIYtNs9e1MrjJh05oB+BuTFn8PSqB/ZO+BZUofDmtFT1B8V6vj/0qqnqP7Gn7OerxrFqvge+vEQ5VbjxJqkgU+265OKJ0+K6mkamHj/27Ub/ABkkW66pq8KPM/Oo0vuVNv8AEq69+1JounST29vp2nWkiLmM6trVtZEnpg+cyRg54/1vXIzWDpv7RF34vtt0Pxd+F3hrfIECT+IrP7T0/hTdMp59+a1X/YO/ZTfr8MJfw8Q6oP5XNOn/AGE/2W7qQS3Xw5vJnAChpPE2rMQB0HNz0rL+wM0r+9i8bOT7Rfs18uSMZfe2/MwWLxkV7lGkvVzl/kvvixsuleGPFE39o+I/2mbO/ggJa5gtNbjitym3kPHHMsJHBPzxkcZ+mZLqv7DXgfVZNd1PxH4E1LVx9+7urxNXuEIz90Zk8ogg/KgXGcADOK0x+wd+yoBj/hWEv/hQap/8k1f0j9i79nTw/L52geD9Z0yTO7dZ+LdYgOeOcpdD0H5CurBcPU8FVdeEIuo9OacqlWVuyc22l3SaTLWbZ8lywqqCtbRy27WXLp5Xscb45+PH7E/xs0oeC/FvjGzeGLmwvJNPu7NrSQcB7e4aJRGy8d9p4yGGRWF4C8VeJ/hR4kN7p/xE0v4n+Cbs7f7b0++iuLyBB0S/SNj8wGcXHTIPmbd2B7bqP7Nnwv1ix/szVpvG97ZkAfZ7nx/r8kWB0G1rwj9K5aH9hb9lq3lE8Xw0mEobeHPiDVGYNnOcm5znNGb5FXzKKmpRjVi7xnFOLjJbP7Sa6NPdNrZs6sHnecYTDPA1+SvQevLLmjyt/ahK83F97aS+0mT2H7Q/hW9Np4N8PeLfCmnX9rBHbzy6zrFvCyOqAEJDv3seD27ciuvh0nwbp1g3j/xz45tNWhsQJW1G9vI47C26cqM7F6jqe4wM1x0n7D37L8xzN8NHkI/va7qR/ncUw/sMfsskFf8AhV5wf+o5qP8A8kVy0shxtaarZo44iad0pSahF9LU1Hl03TlzSXSR7GGnkk6a9tKrTl1UYwqX7+85U2r+jt2Z5l8UP29U1DU5PBP7Ovha98Uas2UOp/YZZ41wcEwWyDzJj6Fti5x94GuDg+If7Y/wtkfxlfaP4/1KC7xPe2+v6Yl9YS+rhLY+bpqgcCNdwzyT2r6o8PfsufB/wjZnT/Cdt4v0W1Y5MGneOtdtoyfXbHeAdz+dav8AwofwR/0HPiJ/4cfxD/8AJtexLLcVXftK1dqXTlVkvx1+ZhUz2vQl7PLadOnS6xlCNWU/+vk5q/8A4KVJLdK6ueA/Br9srwL4s8ZhX0y58N32qjOq6XO4kgMy5zPBIMHI5Loyq2Mkbv4fsKvF9b/Y9+APibUE1bxL4b1/V72P7lzf+MNZuJV+jSXZIr2ioyXKq+VSrQlUUqcnzRSVuVu/Pbyk/estE3J9bLjx2Ko4uUalOkqbtqk2437x5ryivKUptfzPZFFFFe6cIUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABXnPw98ceIde8V67oXijULW3mtZ7n7FpZ8NX2nzC2juGjWYXVxK0V4pTyyWhQBS4yeQK9GrntD8CeHfD+sXev2K6lPqF4GV57/Vru+MaM25khFxI4hQkAlIwq/KvHAwAdDRRRQAUUUUAFFFFADJjMsLtbojyhSUV2KqzY4BIBIGe+D9DXl0fjr4harp+laPpknh6y8Q6jqGrwPdT2U9xZRQ2MzpgRCaN2dv3Yz5ij7zbeNleoTwpcQSW8hcLKhRjHIyMARjhlIKn3BBHauGh+B/w8g0j+xUg19oBePfpJJ4n1OS5jncMJGS4a4MqBwzb1Vwr7juByaAOh8D+IpPF3g7RfE81qttJqljDdSQq25UZlBKgnqAc4PpW5VfT7Cy0qxt9M062jtrS0iSCCGMYWONRhVA7AAAVYoAKKKKACiiigArzfWPGvjuy0zxy1vp+nvf6FNANNjtLC5vz5UiI26SGNlkuGAZm2RhD/AAjONx9Irjo/hP4RhvNav4bjxNHceIMfbpE8VaopJDAgx4uP3BGAAYtmF+UYXigC78PvEEvibwtbanc61a6pc75Irie30m40sCRXIKNaXDvNCy8Aq7ZyM4GcV0lZnh7w5pHhXS00fRLeSK3RmkJluJJ5ZHYlmeSWVmkkckklnYk9zWnQAUUUUAFFFFABXnPjfxv4v8G+I/PA0e/0RbG7vJNPhtpft8UMFs0huXn8zywhlCRBPKz84Ic4Kj0auSuPhZ4NuvFd14zmh1Y6lfosV2i65fLaXCLGYwsloJhbuoVjw0ZGST15oApfD/xP4vv9a1Lw34zk0e4u7awsdVgn0u1lt4xDcmUCFlklkLMjQt+8BAYMPkXGK7quf8I+BPDHgaGeDw5aXMf2kp5kl1f3F5KVQYRBJO7uI1BIVAQq5OAMmugoAKKKKACiiigAri/Heu+MtC1TRH0CbRZLO8vbezlsLi1lkvLwvJiQwyLIqwiKINKWZJMhWBCYye0rlvEHw18K+J/EVl4r1P8AtmPVNOi8iCax12+sVEe8OUaO3mRJFLAEh1OcAHIGKAMPwZ448Qar4+1zw14j1C1tVtprkadpreGr6zmkgilCidb6aUwXalSpIhQbd65I7+i1z2l+BPDuka/c+KLddSn1K5Dr5t9q13eLCrsGdYI55HSBSVXKxKoO0ccCuhoAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKy/Evirwx4M0ebxD4w8R6XoWlW5VZr7UryO1t4yxCqGkkIUZJAGTyTitSvP/AIrHxLHdeEr3QfA2reKLfT9ZN7e22m3FlFKirbzLEx+1zwqVEjoTtYsNudpoA7PRta0fxFpdtrfh/VrPU9OvEElvd2c6TQTJ/eR0JVh7g1dr501/4e/Fkxiw0/SNag/teW71NT4e8RDT7XSb+5u8u1wyzRS3AjgIZUVHjeTzSwGUYX79PiRrtl4xbQn8U6hp2nXt7p2jHR9ShFxfSTyRtJIGnubdfKtiJIRidHH73yyrKpoA98orC8C6fqOleDdF07V4ZYb63sYkuY5dQnvnSXaNwNxO7yy4Ofmd2J/vHrW7QAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAH//Z'

Comment: Does the SVG image have height and width attributes that are not percentages?

Comment: I need to see what dayImgData in order to answer this. Or you could just answer my first comment.

Comment: Yes height and width attributes are percentages

Comment: That's your problem then, change them so they aren't.

Comment: I expected dayImgData to be SVG rather than a jpeg. Where's the SVG?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742180/canvas-todataurl-results-in-solid-black-image

Comment: I'm getting same issue

Comment: I have asked a question again here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323994/google-chart-export-to-pdf-gives-blackbackground-in-mozilla  Hope it is clear:)