# Google Chart Export to PDF gives blackbackground in mozilla

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla, jspdf, google-visualization

I am using following code to export googlechart as pdf. It is working fine in Google Chrome. Whereas in other browsers like mozilla its not woking properly.

Following is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvg.googlecode.com/svn-history/r157/trunk/canvg.js"></script>
<script>
  function getImgData(chartContainer) {
    var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
    var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);

    canvas.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'position: absolute; ' +
        'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
        'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvg(canvas, svg);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log(imgData);
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
    return imgData;
  }

  function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
    var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);

    // Replacing the mime-type will force the browser to trigger a download
    // rather than displaying the image in the browser window.
    window.location = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  }

  function toImg(chartContainer, imgContainer) { 
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var img = doc.createElement('img');
    img.src = getImgData(chartContainer);

    while (imgContainer.firstChild) {
      imgContainer.removeChild(imgContainer.firstChild);
    }
    imgContainer.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    // Pie chart
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 11);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(2, 0, 'Commute');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(3, 0, 'Watch TV');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(4, 0, 'Sleep');
    data.setValue(4, 1, 7);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 450, height: 300, title: 'My Daily Activities'});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_visualization_div"></div>

<button onclick="saveAsImg(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));">Save as PNG Image</button>
<button onclick="toImg(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'), document.getElementById('img_div'));">Convert to image</button>
<hr>
<div id="img_div">
  Image will be placed here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i resolve this issue in different browsers?

The data url formed in two different browsers:

```
Data URL in Chrome :

data:image/png;base64,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

Data URL in Mozilla :

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAcIAAAEsCAYAAABQVrO3AAACIklEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQZ/oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADgMz8EAAH8RQhOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Comment: What precisely does "not working properly" mean? Are there errors in the browser console?

Comment: it not throwing any error in any of the browsers. But what i observed is it is forming different data url's in diifrent browsers.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle so we can see ourselves, or alternatively add the data urls to the question if they aren't huge.

Comment: I have updated the data url's. Sorry i don't know how to create fiddle.

Comment: @jane it 's not working with chrome. & your question shows "It is working fine in Google Chrome".