# Konva stage.toDataUrl() is not rendering the images I see in the canvas?

Tags: canvas, konvajs

I recently started to use the Konva library to create some images online from data being fed by a Web API. The images typically consist of some text, some rectangles, and some small images. The images also come from the same Web API. I convert them into Base64 strings and assign those to the img.src tags. All of this works just fine and when it is done, I see a canvas that has all the text, rects and images as I expect to see it.

The problem comes in when I try to create a PNG from the stage/canvas. The canvas is rendering to an image and all the text and lines are there, but the images are not. At first I was getting an all black background, but then I found the following article that mentions the need to render as a PNG and/or make a non-transparent background. I mention that only because I'm wondering if something similar is going on here?

[canvas.toDataURL results in solid black image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742180/canvas-todataurl-results-in-solid-black-image)

Anyway, here are some code snippets, maybe they will be of help in figuring this out?

```
<div id="container"></div>

const stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();

switch...

    case 'Picture':
    {
        // Get the image from the Web API
        const image = this.store.images.getThumb(
            f.fldData.fldDataValue
        );

        const img = new Image();
        const t = this;

        // Create the Konva.Image() and add it to the stage
        img.onload = function() {
        // resize image keeping aspect ration
            response = t.calculateAspectRatioFit(img, w, h);
            const imgWidth = response.width;
            const imgHeight = response.height;

            const chPicture = new Konva.Image({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                image: img,
                width: imgWidth,
                height: imgHeight
            });

            // add the image to the layer
            layer.add(chPicture);

            // add the layer to the stage
            stage.add(layer);
        };

        image.subscribe(results => {
            // Convert image to Base64
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(results);
            // When it's ready, assign Base64 string to img src
            fileReader.onloadend = () => {
                img.src = fileReader.result;
            };
        });
    }
    break;

...

// Convert the image from the Web API to Base64
const dataURL = stage.toDataURL({
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    quality: 1.0
});

// Resize the image made from the canvas and display it on the screen
const container = document.getElementById('displayImage');
const i = new Image();
i.style.width = '320px';
i.style.height = '196px';
i.src = dataURL;
container.appendChild(i);
```

Comment: Image.onload will fire asynchronously. So at the tine you call toDataURL it ha not been called yet.

Answer (score 1):

`img.onload` works asynchronously. It means the callback function will be executed later when image is loaded.

As I can see you are saving to base64 synchronously after you created a whole stage:

```
// Convert the image from the Web API to Base64
const dataURL = stage.toDataURL({
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    quality: 1.0
});
```

You just need to make sure that ALL images are loaded. And only then conver to dataURL.

Comment: The stage doesn't seem to have an event that fires when it is fully loaded? How can I tell when that has happened so that I can call the .toDataUrl() at the appropriate time?

Comment: @ToddDavis The stage doesn't have such event. But each `new Image();` has `onload` method. Check inside it that all images are loaded.