# ctx.drawImage - black rectangle as result

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have an image (`imgt`) and a resizable and movable crop div (`ram`) and want to crop `imgt` according to size and position of `ram`.

Result - dimensions are ok, but there is no image, just a black rectangle.

```
var img = document.getElementById("imgt");
c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");

var a = $('#imgt').width();
var b = $('#imgt').height();
c1.width = a;
c1.height = b;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, a, b);

ax = $('#ram').position().left;
ay = $('#ram').position().top;
aw = $('#ram').width();
ah = $('#ram').height();

var img = new Image();
img.src = c1.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
c2 = document.createElement("canvas");
c2.width = aw;
c2.height = ah;

var ctx = c2.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, ax, ay, aw, ah, 0, 0, aw, ah);

var dl = document.createElement("a");
dl.href = c2.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
dl.download = true;
document.body.appendChild(dl);
dl.click();
```

Comment: Your `var ctx` is defined twice - could this be the issue?

Comment: @AnisR., no, they are for different canvas. I tried to change but the same result.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(c1.toDataURL('image/jpeg'))`? I suspect that your `src` is wrong or invalid, and hence the black rect

Comment: @Samleo, result - `data:image/jpeg;base64,...`

Comment: Is your canvas's background transparent? If so, then converting to PNG instead of JPEG in `toDataURL()` should fix it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742180/canvas-todataurl-results-in-solid-black-image

Comment: @AnisR., doesn't help anything

Comment: 1. You may consider using `img.onload = function() {ctx.drawImage(...` 2. I would need to know the size of your image because you may draw the image outside the canvas: `ctx.drawImage(img, ax, ay, aw, ah, 0, 0, aw, ah);`. 3. You should avoid using `ctx`  twice. why not using `ctx2` the second time? And the same for the image. A nice way to debug your code would be appending the canvases to the DOM to see what happens.